# Format number in Struts 2 <s:property/> tag

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

I would like to format number displayed by `<s:property value="summary.total"/>` tag in Struts 2. There is a `double` value. How can I do that? Should I use `OGNL`?

Or maybe I must use `<s:text/>` tag and define my format in resuource file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `<s:text/>` with `<s:param/>`.

Property file:

> ```java
> summary.cost= € {0,number,##0.00}
> ```

JSP:

```xml
<s:text name="summary.cost"> 
    <s:param name="value" value="summary.total"/> 
</s:text>
```

[**This** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20520668/1654265) explains how to use `#` and `0` in the format mask.

Comment: Yeah, I found that, but I thought that maybe there is something quicker :)

Comment: A `double` value, and €?  I surely hope that you don't use floating point numbers for currency.

Comment: I never mentioned € and Trick never mentioned `double` ;)

Comment: Quicker is only with <s:date/> tag, which has format attribute. You can, of course, implement your own tag, which could have formatting included :)

Answer (score 18):

The way more fast

```
<s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',{summary.total})"/>
```

Lucky!!

Answer (score 5):

This one is quicker:

```
<s:property value="getText('struts.money.format', {summary.cost})" />
```

And in your properties file this:

```
struts.money.format= {0,number,\u00A4##0.00}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 3):

i had this problem to format a number in this way 1.234,56

so i prefered both tags struts tag and fmt tag(fmt because s:number don't exist)

so i used the following syntaxe:

```
 <s:label label="mylabel">
    <s:param name="value">
        <s:text  name="">
    <fmt:formatNumber  maxFractionDigits="2" pattern="#.###"  >1234.56</fmt:formatNumber>
        </s:text>   
    </s:param>      
 </s:label>
```

and it's work

Answer (score 2):

If your property is not number in your action then the getText will not work on it. The pattern accept numbers only. In this case you can go with fmt as mentioned by @sarie

```
<fmt:formatNumber groupingUsed="true" type="currency" value="${amount}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The most quickiest and easiest way is to use `<s:number />` tag.

Example:

```
<s:number name="%{summary.total}" minimumFractionDigits="2" type="currency" currency="USD" />
```

More about tag here https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/Number.html