# Using Struts2 Tags to Formatting Numbers

Tags: java, struts2, format, bigdecimal, number-formatting

I want to format some numbers in our jsp pages.
first i define some resources in my porperties
`format.number.with2Decimal={0,number,#0.00}`

......
Question1:
i want to know what is the ‘#’ and '0' means?
0.00,#0.00,##.00,###0.00
who can tell me the differences between them? thanks!

Question2:
if i define a BigDecimal type in my action 
BigDecimal number1;

Then my page should using a format to show this value,
`1.if number1=null then show  -NIL-`
`2.if number1=0    then show  -NIL-`
`3.if number1>0    then show   1.00,3434.98 .....`
please ignore number<0

Question3:
change number1 to a String,
`1.if number1=null or empty or blank     then show  -NIL-`
`2.if number1=Hello                      then show   Hello ....`

could you give me help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question1: i want to know what is the ‘`#`’ and '`0`' means?
>   `0.00`,`#0.00`,`##.00`,`###0.00` who can tell me the differences between them? thanks!

- `0` means that a number must be printed, no matter if it exists
- `#` means that a number must be printed if it exists, omitted otherwise.

Example:

```
    System.out.println("Assuming US Locale: " + 
                             "',' as thousand separator, " + 
                             "'.' as decimal separator   ");

    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0##");
    System.out.println("\n==============================");
    System.out.println("With Format (#,##0.0##) ");
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.println("1234.0 = " + nf.format(1234.0));
    System.out.println("123.4  = " + nf.format(123.4));
    System.out.println("12.34  = " + nf.format(12.34));
    System.out.println("1.234  = " + nf.format(1.234));
    System.out.println("==============================");

    nf = new DecimalFormat("#,000.000");
    System.out.println("\n==============================");
    System.out.println("With Format (#,000.000) ");
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.println("1234.0 = " + nf.format(1234.0));
    System.out.println("123.4  = " + nf.format(123.4));
    System.out.println("12.34  = " + nf.format(12.34));
    System.out.println("1.234  = " + nf.format(1.234));
    System.out.println("==============================");
```

<kbd>[**Running Example**](http://ideone.com/goqADm)</kbd>

Output:

> ```
> Assuming US Locale: ',' as thousand separator, '.' as decimal separator)
>
> ==============================
> With Format (#,##0.0##) 
> ------------------------------
> 1234.0 = 1,234.0
> 123.4  = 123.4
> 12.34  = 12.34
> 1.234  = 1.234
> ==============================
>
> ==============================
> With Format (#,000.000) 
> ------------------------------
> 1234.0 = 1,234.000
> 123.4  = 123.400
> 12.34  = 012.340
> 1.234  = 001.234
> ==============================
> ```

In Struts2, you can apply this kind of format with the `getText()` function from `ActionSupport`.

P.S: Question 2 and 3 are trivial (and messy).

Answer (score 5):

Here you go :

```
<s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',{profit})"/>
```

This is how I format numbers in my projects. You can use it with `<s:if>` to attain what you require.

Comment: Not work ` <td width="50px"><s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,###0.00}',${rv.fconsume })"/> </td>`

Comment: not work `<s:property value="{0,${rv.fconsume },#,###0.00}"/>`

Comment: @Gank variable name is supposed to be enclosed in `{}` and not in  `${}`