# JSTL c:set and Struts s:set are undesirably formatting numbers

Tags: struts2, jstl

```
<c:set var="xmlDocumentId" value="${id}" scope="request" />
<s:set var="xmlDocumentId" value="%{id}" scope="request" />
```

are formatting id based on locale, setting xmlDocumentId to `"12,345"` while:

```
<c:out value="${id}" />
<s:property value="%{id}" />
```

are outputting "12345".

Any ideas how to break this behavior?

Comment: Remove scope="request".

Comment: Removing scope makes the variable unavailable to where it is being used.

Comment: Where do you want to use it?

Comment: In the request. It is being used by a property to generate a link to the document.

e.g.
    xmlDocumentUrl=xmlDocument.action?xmlDocumentId={xmlDocumentId}
    
    <s:property value="getText('xmlDocumentUrl')" />

I can work around this by creating another accessor that returns the id as a string rather than a long, but I'd rather learn why c:set and s:set are formatting numbers.

Comment: How do you construct url-s? Use S2 tag to do that. Then there is no need to put it in the request.

Comment: I have a business requirement that URLs be defined in a properties file and not embedded in the JSP. I have no control over that.

There are lots of workarounds that remove my need to understand this issue, nevertheless, I would like to learn the answer to the question of how to use set tags (or some other jsp tag) to bypass formatting and do a straight-up number-to-String conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are getting value with `getText` or `<s:text>` tag your long value gets formatted according to locale. To prevent this from happening convert your long to string.

With `<s:set>` tag you can call `toString()` method directly in `value` attribute.

```
<s:set var="xmlDocumentId" value="id.toString()" scope="request" />
```

For the concrete formatting algorithm take a look at [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class and its `subformat` method.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know [how to format numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20520668/1654265), in Struts2 `<s:property/>` tag you can use `getText()` to format your number in the desired way, for example :

```xml
<s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0}',{id})"/>
```

Comment: Andrea: Thank you, but the issue is that the set tag is formatting my numbers when I do not want it to. How do I stop the set tag from formatting numbers?

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<s:text name="id" > <s:param name="value" value="id"/> </s:text>
```