# struts2 format currency thousand separator

Tags: java, struts2, locale, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I have a Struts 2 project where I display an item price. I want to change the format accorting to localization.

For example:

```
 locale en_GB : 75.9
 locale el_GR : 75,9
```

Currently I use the format in the messages for both locales :

```
{0,number,##0.00}
```

I tried changing the format in the one language to:

```
{0,number,##0,00}
```

but then the displayed price was wrong as: `0,76` (moved everything to the decimal part).

Any suggestions?

---

EDIT:

Note that in my case i want to FORCE the comma as decimal separator for all locales in the application.

Comment: Can you show how do you use this format?

Comment: This is how I use it: <s:text name="format.currency"><s:param value="item.price"/></s:text>

Comment: The decimal separator depends on locale. S2 will format numbers according to current locale so just leave `{0,number,##0.00}` that pattern and it should work.

Comment: Probably the error is just `gr_GR` instead of `el_GR`. BTW one could be interested in showing multiple localized strings (and numbers) in a locale-independent page (eg. a banner with the selection of the language, each name written in its language)...

Comment: The question is not only for el_GR, it could be for any language. I want to force the comma as decimal separator for all locales

Comment: Why do you want to force that? Each locale has it own decimal separator and by changing it you are confusing users of your application.

Comment: Because the client requires to be able to view the application on two different languages, but to have everywhere the same way to represent prices.

Comment: Woah... the client is alway right, isn't it ? :/ Then you can use the code in the answer provided, with the default locale chosen, in a method of a BaseAction of your, extended by the other actions, and called only to format currencies.

Comment: @Panos: Then don't format prices through S2 localization feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DecimalFormat Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols%29) accepting both a pattern and a [DecimalFormatSymbols](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html), created by [its constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#DecimalFormatSymbols%28java.util.Locale%29) taking a Locale:

```java
Locale greekLocale = new Locale("el", "GR");

// Thousands separator, decimal separator etc...
DecimalFormatSymbols greekDFS = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(greekLocale);

// Your pattern, their symbols
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0##", greekDFS);
```

Take a look at the <kbd>[running demo](http://ideone.com/yzEMoE)</kbd>. I've used [`el_GR`](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/el-GR/) by the way, with `gr_GR` it seems that the decimal separator is still the dot. Not sure what `gr_GR` is.

P.S: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20520668/1654265) is an answer related to formatting patterns and TextProvider in Struts2, that might help future visitors