# Calculation with <s:property /> values in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I have the following code:

```xml
<s:property value="currentPrice" />
<s:property value="oldPrice" />
<span class="badge">-50%</span>
```

Now I want to display the percentage in the `<span>` tag by the formula:

> percentage = (currentPrice - oldPrice) / oldPrice * 100

How can I do that in Struts2 ?

Comment: Why js? Do it at the backend. Or if you insist on doing it in jsp just use `<s:property>` tag. What the problem?

Comment: Right, I've be confused concepts. Now I've fixed problem with property and tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Client side** solution:

```xml
<s:property value="currentPrice" />
<s:property value="oldPrice" />
<span class="badge">
    <s:property value="%{((currentPrice - oldPrice) / oldPrice) * 100}" />%
</span>
```

Or in alternative,

**Server side** solution:

```java
public Integer getPercentage(){
    return ((currentPrice - oldPrice) / oldPrice) * 100;
}
```

```xml
<s:property value="currentPrice" />
<s:property value="oldPrice" />
<span class="badge">
    <s:property value="percentage" />%
</span>
```

Comment: While I accept your answer because it provides the correct result, here is my our solution:
`<s:set name="percent" value="%{(#currentPrice-#oldPrice)/#oldPrice*100}" />
<s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',{#percent})" />%`

Comment: Actually, I'm new to Struts2 and I don't know when to use the character #. In addition, if I put your code (client side) into the getText function, it doesn't show the value. Can you help explain?

Comment: If `currentPrice` and `oldPrice` are action attributes, there is no need to use the `#`. BTW if with `I don't know when to use the character #` you mean in **OGNL**, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007858/whats-the-difference-between-and-signs-in-struts-tags), if instead you mean in the **getText()** pattern, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20520668/1654265). In every case, please consider **upvoting** every answer that you've found helpful, to express your appreciation for the efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using javascript like below -

```
var currentPrice = document.getElementById("currentPrice").value;
var oldPrice = document.getElementById("oldPrice").value;
var percentage = (currentPrice-oldPrice)/oldPrice * 100
```

Comment: Why javascript? What is `"currentPrice"`, `"oldPrice"`?