# How to format currency in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, ognl

I have the following code in Struts

```
<fmt:formatNumber  type="currency" currencySymbol="Rs" value="${product.priceSell + product.priceSell * rates[nr.count - 1]}" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2"/>
```

I want to convert it into Struts2. I tried below code, but its not working.

```
<s:text name="format.money">
    <s:param name="value" value="%{#product.priceSell+ #product.priceSell * #rates[#nr.count - 1]}" />
</s:text>
```

Note: rates is an `Arraylist<String>`.

Comment: Check this link [Money Format](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html) and [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558662/format-number-in-struts-2-sproperty-tag) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSTL `fmt` tag in Struts2. JSP EL expression searches all scopes and `valueStack` in Struts2. Analogous to this for OGNL would be `#attr` prefix. So, to access scoped variables, and search in all scopes  you should try something like

```
"%{#attr.product.priceSell+ #attr.product.priceSell * #attr.rates[#attr.nr.count - 1]}"
```

Note, the values in the expression should not be of type `String`. If you keep the values as strings, then it needs to parse them before using in the expression as a valid numbers and this better do in the action rather than in JSP.